# jquery DataTables Editor: "select" field displays option value instead of label

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery's DataTables which is really working great. Then only problem I got is, that I am facing (in non-edit-view) the value of the select-field (which is an id). The user of course doesn't want to see the id of course. 
Therefore I am looking for a possibility to configure that column in a way to show always the value of label property.

Here a some snippets:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var table = $('#overviewTable').DataTable({
            dom: "Tfrtip",
            ajax: "/Conroller/GetTableData",
            columns: [
                { data: "Id", className: "readOnly", visible: false },
                {
                    data: "LoanTransactionId",
                    className: "readOnly readData clickable",
                    "fnCreatedCell": function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html("<a href='#'>" + oData.LoanTransactionId + "</a>");
                    }
                },
                { data: "Id", className: "readOnly" },
                { data: "property_1", className: "readOnly" },
                { data: "Priority" },
                { data: null, className: "action readOnly", defaultContent: '<a href="#">Info</a>' }
            ],
            order: [1, 'asc'],
            tableTools: {
                sRowSelect: "os",
                sRowSelector: 'td:first-child',
                aButtons: []
            }
        });

        // data reload every 30 seconds
        setInterval(function() {
            table.ajax.reload();
        }, 30000);

        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
            ajax: "PostTable",
            table: "#overviewTable",
            fields: [
                {
                    label: "Id",
                    name: "Id"
                },
                {
                    label: "Column 1",
                    name: "property_1"
                }, 
                {
                    label: "Priority",
                    name: "Priority",
                    type: "select",
                    options: [
                        { label: "low", value: 0 },
                        { label: "mid", id: 1 },
                        { text: "high", id: 2 }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        // Inline Edit - only those who are not readOnly
        $('#overviewTable').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child .readOnly)', function(e) {
            editor.inline(this, {
                submitOnBlur: true
            });
        });
```

How it looks in the display mode

[image: column in display view]

How it looks in the edit mode

[image: cell in edit view]

Comment: Not totally sure what you're trying to do. I don't know what you mean by this: "I am facing (in non-edit-view) the value of the select-field (which is an id)" Hiding columns is pretty simple, but not sure that's what you want to do.

Comment: I don't want to hide the column. When I am not in inline-edit mode I see the drop down list, which is totally fine. But when I am in display mode the dataTable displays the id's and not the label value... So I don't want to see the id's at all...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, I used Bae's option 2 (rendering function) back then. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

You want to modify your column options for `priority`

**Preferred Option: Your data source has a field with the priority as a string**

This is the best option, as you don't want to have two places with this business logic. Keep it out of the client code.

Also, you will want to modify the editor as well so that the options used have been retrieved dynamically from the server to keep this business logic out of the client too. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Since you don't provide details on what your data structure looks lik, I'm assuming it is an object, and it has an attribute `priorityAsString` so use the `string` option type for `render`.

```
        columns: [
            ...
            { 
              data: "Priority" ,
              render: "priorityAsString",
            },
```

**Option 2) You write a function to map priority to string**

Do this if you can't get the data from the server. But remember you will need to update many places when the priority list changes.

```
        columns: [
            ...
            { 
              data: "Priority" ,
              render: renderPriorityAsString,
            },
        ...

function renderPriorityAsString(priority) {
  const priorityToString = {
     0: 'low',
     1: 'med',
     2: 'high',    
  };
  return priorityToString[priority] || `${priority} does not have a lookup value`;
}
```

Comment: What about the fields in the data table editor instead of the data table `columns` option? In my case, I would like to change the label displayed  in the options to contain some other information

Answer (score -1):

```
"render": function ( data, type, full ) { return label;}
```